# Mule CXF web service client: "no such endpoint"

Tags: java, mule, cxf

I am trying to connect to a soap ws with cxf using mule. All I want is to call an external ws with a payload and get the response back into the flow.

My configuration looks sort of like this:

```
<flow name="flow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer class="WsPayload" doc:name="WsPayload"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="createCustomer" decoupledEndpoint="http://localhost:8088/test" port="ServicePort" serviceClass="CustomerService" doc:name="CXF" />
</flow>
```

The problem I have is that I get this response:

```
No such operation: createCustomer. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: CreateCustomerRequest
```

I have tried just about everything. I know the service is there, it is currently running as a mock service in soap ui. Any idea why this fails? Also, are there better ways to do this in mule?

Comment: Could you post ur WSDL and which version of Mule are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Webservices connector to call the external WS?  As long as you have the WSDL you should be able to pull in the service you want with that connector.

Hope that helps!